# Connecting to a Vista shared folder from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I have 2 computers: one is on Vista and the other one is on Windows 7. I made a shared folder on my vista computer and tried adding it from my windows 7 computer. I keep getting the following message when trying to click on my Vista computer from my Windows 7:

> Windows cannot access *\\COMPUTER-NAME*
>
> You do not have permission to access *\\COMPUTER-NAME*. Contact your network administrator to request access.

How do you access a Vista shared drive from Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

I *finally* found where was the problem.

In "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings", I had to select "Use user accounts and passwords to connect to other computers" instead of "Allow Windows to manage homegroup connections (recommended)."

[image]

Comment: This could be the solution i seek.